# Rails Search with Multiple Values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord, associations

So let's say I have  Two Model Post & Category.

Post has_many Categories

Now,I want to search Post based on category?

Example:

Post 1 has categories 2,5,6

Post 2 has categories 5,9

Post 3 has categories 2,4,8

Now In search User Select categories 2,4,8

In Result page Display like this

Post 3

Post 1

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
class Post

  def self.with_categories(*category_ids)
    joins(:categories).where(categories: {id: category_ids}).select("#{table_name}.*, COUNT(#{Category.table_name}.id AS match_count").group("#{table_name}.id").order(:match_count)
  end
end

Post.with_categories(2,4,8)
```

Comment: Hi one doubt  table_name  means what ?

Comment: `table_name` is a method defined on an ActiveRecord class returning name of the table used for given model. In most cases it is just pluralized underscored name of the class, but it is not always true (if you for example use STI)